# Initializing an empty sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to create an empty Sinatra application with a config.ru file. Right now the only way I know how is to initialise it with cucumber but doing that creates extra files which I don't need including step definitions etc. When I run 'gem install Sinatra' in my working directory it says:

Successfully installed sinatra-1.4.5
Parsing documentation for sinatra-1.4.5
Done installing documentation for sinatra after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

Yet there is no config.ru file.

How do I initialise a Sinatra app so I have just the config.ru?

Comment: Paul's answer is good, but if you really want a rackup file, look in the docs for how to run a modular app, and use what you've got from Paul's answer to build on.

Answer (score 2):

From the [sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20a%20Classic%20Style%20Application%20with%20a%20config.ru)

first create a file called app.rb in your working directory containing the following code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

now create a file called config.ru with the following content:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

now run

```
rackup -p4567
```

to run the application